# A subset of the real numbers which has only unilateral limit/accumulation points is countable.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, elementary-set-theory

I have been thinking about this problem for a while and couldn't find a solution by myself and the one that I've heard about is a little difficult.

If no one posts that solution, I will do it latter.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S\subseteq\mathbb R$ and assume that no element of $S$ is a bilateral (two-sided) limit point of $S.$ This means that, for each $x\in S,$ there is a number $\varepsilon\gt0$ such that either $(x,\ x+\varepsilon)$ or $(x-\varepsilon,\ x)$ is disjoint from $S.$ In other words, we have
$$S=A\cup B$$
where
$$A=\{x\in S:\exists\varepsilon\gt0,\ (x,\ x+\varepsilon)\cap S=\emptyset\}$$
and
$$B=\{x\in S:\exists\varepsilon\gt0,\ (x-\varepsilon,\ x)\cap S=\emptyset\}.$$
For each $x\in A$ choose $\varepsilon_x\gt0$ so that $(x,\ x+\varepsilon_x)\cap A=\emptyset.$ If $x,y\in A$ and $x\lt y$ then $x\lt x+\varepsilon_x\le y\lt y+\varepsilon_y,$ so the intervals $(x,\ x+\varepsilon_x)$ and $(y,\ y+\varepsilon_y)$ are disjoint. Since any set of pairwise disjoint open intervals of $\mathbb R$ is countable, the set $A$ is countable. A similar argument shows that $B$ is countable. It follows that $S$ is countable, since $S$ is the union of two countable sets.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was very helpful. I was thinking in a similar argument, but I did it on $S$ instead. So the argument became invalid.